# Issue with Xml Project

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

I'm looking for some help.

I created an `mp3` web service using visual studio c# and `xml` to store the data.  I created a method that will allow a user to create a new playlist id to be stored to the `xml` document.  I set my `xml` file as follows:

```
public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    //used as an access path to the xml file
    string xmlFileName = "F:\\WebServices\\Mp3Server\\SongList.xml";
```

This is before any of the methods in my program.

My `songlist.xml` file is stored correctly and is the correct path from what I can see.

I currently had `mp3` id's stored on the `songlist.xml` file is as follows:

```
<Playlist ID="123">
    <Song Title="Bump">
        <Artist>Ed Sheeran</Artist>
        <Album>Asylum</Album>
        <Year>2011</Year>
        <Genre>Folk</Genre>
    </Song> 
    <Song Title="3 AM">
        <Artist>Matchbox Twenty</Artist>
        <Album>Exile On Mainstream</Album>
        <Year>2007</Year>
        <Genre>Rock</Genre>
    </Song>
</Playlist>
```

The code I wrote to create a new playlist id is as follows:

```
//creates a new playlist
[WebMethod]
public string createPlaylistName(string playlistID)
{
    string errorMessage = "";
    List<string> playlistNames = createPlaylist("/SongList//Playlist/ID");
    if (playlistNames.Contains(playlistID))
    {
        errorMessage = "error! Id already exists";
    }
    else
    {
        string xpath = "/SongList/Playlist[@ID'" + playlistID + "']";
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(xmlFileName);
        XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
        XmlNode playistNode = root.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
        XmlElement playList = doc.CreateElement("Playlist");
        XmlAttribute ID = doc.CreateAttribute("ID");
        ID.Value = playlistID;
        playList.Attributes.Append(ID);
        playistNode.InsertAfter(playList, playistNode.LastChild);
        doc.Save(xmlFileName);
        errorMessage = "success";

    }
    return errorMessage;
}
```

But when I run the program, create a new playlist Id and invoke the command: it displays "page not found" webpage.

I can't figure out why the create method is crashing.

If anyone can give any advice, I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: Have you tried adding breakpoints to see where specifically in your code is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried stepping through it?  You'll find that it fails because your XPath expression isn't valid.  Your concatenation creates an expression like this:

```
/SongList/Playlist[@ID'123']
```

Where it should be:

```
/SongList/Playlist[@ID='123']
```

I'm also not entirely sure the logic makes sense.  You're checking that a playlist *doesn't* exist with that ID and then adding one.  So how is your XPath expression supposed to return an element?

As an aside, you should probably look into LINQ to XML  - it's a much nicer API, for example:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(xmlFileName);

var playlist = doc.Descendants("Playlist")
    .Single(e => (string)e.Attribute("ID") == "123");

playlist.AddAfterSelf(
    new XElement("Playlist",
        new XAttribute("ID", "456")
        ));
```

Comment: Thanks guys, I figured it out and got what I was looking for to work.